# rails4 on mac osx 10.6.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-snow-leopard

I'm new in rails and work on Ubuntu. Now I have old mac (osx 10.6.8 - snow leopard), will I have any problems to install latest ruby, rails 4 and git. I read that for latest git needs xcode that doesn't support on 10.6.8.

My question is can I use rails4, git, homebrew and rvm on mac osx 10.6.8. I'm code with my team who use latest versions. Maybe I will have problems in future trying to install capistrano or some other useful rails gems?
Will I have problems if I use not latest version of git, and my teammates does?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Install Homebrew
- Install Git and Curl (it will be useful when you install RVM) using Homebrew
- Install RVM
- Install Ruby using RVM
- Install Rails using Ruby and Bundler

RVM allow you to have any versions of Ruby you want, and if you will have desired Ruby version you will not have the problem with gems.

It is possible that you will have some difficulties with native gems which you need to compile, but I think it is possible to solve it.

Comment: I am afraid that I will have a problem in the future. Problems which I do not know now. Do you think that fears no reason?

Comment: You can have problems with some rare native gems, but anyway, you can try.

Comment: If you use RVM, you can set each project to have its own gemset as well as specify ruby versions. You theoretically shouldn't encounter any problems at all. That is what RVM was designed for

Comment: Homebrew doesn't seem to work on osx 10.6.8 because Xcode doesn't support it anymore. There is no xcode-select command available.